# Transformation of sinusoids

Tags: geometry

We want to get $h(x)= 0.29\cos(3x+4.2)$

$ y = \cos x$ -> multiply $x$-axis 0,29 -> $y=0.29\cos x$ -> multiply $y$-axis $1/3$ -> $y=0.29\cos(3x)$ -> translation $(-1,4;0)$ -> $h(x) = 0.29\cos(3x+4.2)$

Is this correct? I know you can more easily translate first, however I like to use as a rule of thumb to always multiply before translating.

Answer (score 0):

The $0.29$ has the effect of shrinking in the vertical ($y$-axis) direction.  The reason for that should become apparent if you think about plotting points.  Similarly, the $3$ shrinks in the $x$-direction.

You really should learn *why* these things work the way they do by thinking about graphs.  That way, if you forget how it works, you'll know how to figure it out.

Comment: Thank you kind sir, but that was not my question. My question was whether my answer is correct or not

Comment: @ylykcoitus : I think my answer should make it clear that yours is not correct.